# What is ActivityInfo meta data?

Tags: android

What is ActivityInfo's meta data?

```
Bundle bundle = actInfo.metaData;
```

What kind of data bundle contains and how to retrieve data from Bundle if no key pair known?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's whatever meta data was specified in the Activity's manifest.

```
<activity>
    <meta-data android:name="key" android:value="value" />
    <meta-data android:name="key2" android:resource="@string/res" />
</activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Bundle has a method called keySet which returns `Set<String>`.  With that, you can iterate through all the data with Bundle.getString, getInt, getBoolean, getFloat.  I don't think there is a way to know the correct/intended data type though.